# ¡Soy quien fue! o ¡Soy quien fui! o ¡Soy quien era!

Tags: tiempos-verbales, conjugación

Quisiera saber si estas oraciones son correctas, ya que una de las duda que tengo es con respecto a dicha conjugación después del relativo “quien”/“la que”, y también si estas oraciones son correctas.

> ¡Yo soy quien/la que **fue**!
>
> ¡Yo soy quien/la que **fui**!
>
> ¡Yo soy quien/la que **era**!

Asimismo luego de revisar en el DPD, mi segunda duda radica en que tiempo debe estar el verbo, ya que según los ejemplos que da el DPD están en presente simple.

> 4.13. yo soy el que (o quien), tú eres o vos sos el que (o quien) + verbo. Se trata de oraciones copulativas enfáticas cuyo atributo es una oración de relativo sin antecedente expreso. Si el sujeto del verbo ser es un pronombre de primera o de segunda persona del singular (yo, tú/vos), el verbo de la oración de relativo puede ir, bien en tercera persona del singular, en concordancia estricta con su sujeto gramatical (el/la que o quien), opción mayoritaria en el habla culta: «Yo soy el que **manda** acá» (Soriano León [Arg. 1986]); bien en primera o segunda persona del singular, concordando con el sujeto del verbo ser, opción habitual en el habla coloquial y que expresa mayor implicación afectiva por parte del hablante: «Por primera vez en mi vida yo soy la que **tengo** el control» (Santiago Sueño [P. Rico 1996]). Si se invierte el orden y la oración de relativo antecede al verbo ser, es menos frecuente que el verbo aparezca en primera o segunda persona; así, es más normal decir El que **manda** soy yo que El que **mando** soy yo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como explica el DPD en el párrafo que citas, las dos oraciones

> Yo soy la que fue
>
> Yo soy la que fui

son gramaticalmente correctas. Suenan un poco extrañas por el uso repetido del verbo *ser*: otras formas más comunes de decir lo mismo son

> Yo soy la que lo hizo
>
> Yo soy la que lo hice

o incluso "fui yo". En todos los casos, la que habla está confesando que ella realizó la acción de la que se está hablando.

La construcción con *era* se usa a veces en negativo con un significado completamente distinto. Por ejemplo:

> Yo ya no soy la que era cuando me conociste

Quien dice esta frase está diciendo que ha pasado mucho tiempo desde que la conociste, y que ella misma ha cambiado mucho desde entonces (ya sean cambios físicos o de personalidad).

Comment: Me encanta tu último ejemplo.  Para las frases que propuso Laura, la versión más sencilla (que mencionaste) es más práctica (Fui yo, Yo fui, Era yo).

Comment: Muchas gracias wimi por responderme y ayudarme a esclarecer mis dudas. Sino, que en un musical A menciona "A tu hogar has de volver." y B responde "¡Soy quien fue!", ya que siempre había creído que lo correcto era "Soy quien fui". No obstante, en este detalle extra que doy, en mi opinión no tiene coherencia entre el hilo de la conversación.

Comment: Leí las dos letras (https://genius.com/Idina-menzel-and-evan-rachel-wood-show-yourself-lyrics y https://genius.com/Carmen-sarahi-muestrate-lyrics) y veo que no hay mucha correspondencia entre una y otra.  Por otra parte, cuando se traduce y se adapta una letra, hay que adaptarse al ritmo.  Mejor hubiera sido algo así: *Ya encontré a quien buscaba, y resulta que soy yo* -- pero no se acomodan tantas sílabas.